# insert data from another table mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to add values from table to another , but in first table i have foreign keys 
how to insert it's values ?

```
insert into student(first_name)
select * from `TABLE 13`
set school_id = 1
```

school_id is the forign key how to set it's values to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO student(first_name,school_id)
SELECT first_name, 1 FROM `TABLE 13`
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a8198/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
insert into student(first_name)
VALUES( select first_name from `TABLE 13` WHERE school_id = 1 LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: instead of where i want to insert to school_id specific value "1"